# Handle 403-error in Spring

Tags: spring, exception, handle, http-status-code-403

I want to handle 403 error to show normal message:

```
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String accessDeniedException () {
        return "my message";
    }
```

But AccessDeniedException not handle 403 error.

Same not working follow:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    @ExceptionHandler(SecurityException.class)
    @ResponseBody
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, If an exception is not being thrown by the code called through your controller, you can't handle it by using `@ExceptionHandler` (or @ControllerAdvice). For example, exceptions thrown directly from Spring Security, like the CSRF exception, can't be caught this way.

Comment: maybe another way to do it?

Comment: Can't think of an easy way. Maybe a filter. But as @dimitrissli says, if you want to handle Spring security's 403, you can follow the link she has provided, or else use something like .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint()) if you are using JavaConfig.

Answer (score 2):

This most likely is coming via `Spring Security`. If that's the case you need to setup and register an `access-denied-handler`.

[Here is a detailed tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/customize-http-403-access-denied-page-in-spring-security/) of how to do that.